# Why rotate an image can't be full height - React Native

Tags: css, react-native

I'm trying to rotate an image from an url and rotate to put it kind of full size. but when rotate it seems that there is a problem with the height/width and can't be taller than the width.

```
<Image
   style={{
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      transform: [{ rotate: '90deg'}],
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
   }}
   source={{
      uri: 'https://myUrl',
   }}
/>
```

[image: without transform it looks like that]

This is without transform.

[image]

And when i add the transform to the style i got that. seems that the height is actually the width of the parent.

Comment: A transform is **purely visual**  it does not affect the size of the element.

Comment: The width of the img stays the same - and will be whatever you set it to. If you know the height of the container you want the img to be in (say in vh units) then set the width of the img to that and rotate it. If not you may need JS.

Comment: try width:100% without height

Comment: If you give us more context - how is the height of the container ascertained? - we may be able to help. You need to set the width of the image to the height of the container you want it rotated in.

Comment: @AHaworth just a `<View style={{flex: 1}}></View>`. that's take all the empty space from the header to the bottom bar.

Comment: @PushpikaWan same result.

Comment: The height seems cap. even i put height or width 9000 i got the same result.